# sklearn: give param to F1 score in gridsearchCV/Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, multiclass-classification, gridsearchcv

I have setup a `sklearn.GridsearchCV` with a `Pipeline` as the estimator. My problem is a multiclass classification. I clearly receive this error:

```
ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'].
```

Which is because I use `F1` score without setting the `average` argument. My question is **where exactly should I pass this argument to the object?**

my code:

```
estimator = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=Pipeline(setting['layers']),
    param_grid=setting['hyper_parameters'],
    cv=cv,
    scoring=self.scoring,
    refit=self.refit_metric,
    n_jobs=n_jobs,
    return_train_score=True,
    verbose=True
)
```

and then:

```
estimator.fit(
    self.x_train,
    self.y_train
)
```

The error is raised on the `.fit()` line, but I guess I should pass the parameter when instantiating the `GridsearchCV`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `scoring` parameter of the `GridSearchCV`, you can just pass e.g. `f1_weighted` as a string. That should do the trick. You can have a look at the [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#the-scoring-parameter-defining-model-evaluation-rules) for possible values.

Comment: Ah I was aware that I can pass it a string like `f1`, but then I was not too smart to check the list of the values!!! Thanks a lot!